# How to create a database in Azure?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-sql-database, dreamspark

I'm creating a web-app following [the next guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-deploy-aspnet-mvc-app-membership-oauth-sql-database/). I need to have a sql database hosted in Azure portal. In Aure hosting settings I choose existing sql server (with no database) then choose to create new database. But when I create new ASP.NET MVC project but failed. Azure portal says

```
Tracking Id: 73aabcd6-7cdc-4bf5-9590-a55eb0cfe279
Status:    Conflict
Provisioning State:    Failed
Timestamp:    4/24/2016, 12:36:23 PM
Duration:    PT32.4858855S
Type:    Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases
Resource Id:    /subscriptions/a56b3a76-22b0-4d67-a3dd-f726672d2b2f/resourceGroups/Isolenta29ResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/isolenta29dbserver/databases/Isolenta29Database
StatusMessage:    {
  "status": "Failed",
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
    "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.",
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "40827",
        "message": "The operation is not supported for your subscription offer type."
      }
    ]
  }
}
Resource:    isolenta29dbserver/Isolenta29Database
```

I have a DreamSpark Subscription and already know it provides only one free Database. So what went wrong? How to create a databas ehosted in Azure and use it in web apps?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Dreamspark already have the support of SQL DB (however, not long ago there was no such support), but i suspect that it can be some kind of intermittent problem. You should be able to use MySQL. That is the [tutorial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devschool/2015/06/29/azure-and-dreamspark-connecting-your-webapp-to-your-mysql-database/).

Answer (score 0):

as states in the error message 

`"message": "The operation is not supported for your subscription offer type."`

seems like your DreamSpark subscription is not allowed to create any SQL database.
either you upgrade your subscription or try to use file base database that can site together with your site.